# Q: mouseleave not triggered when expected in A-frame

Tags: javascript, aframe

I'm trying to change the colour of some dynamically created box entities when the user mouses over/out from them.

They always successfully change on `mouseenter`, however it seems like `mouseleave` isn't always triggered so sometimes they keep the hover colour.

This is a basic version of my app:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.8.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      const COLOURS = {
        default: '#ff0000',
        hover: '#ffff00'
      };

      const blockMouseEnter = event => {
        event.target.setAttribute('material', 'color', COLOURS.hover);
      };

      const blockMouseLeave = event => {
        event.target.setAttribute('material', 'color', COLOURS.default);
      };

      AFRAME.registerComponent('stacks', {
        init: function() {
          const sceneElement = document.querySelector('a-scene');

          for (var stackHeight = 0; stackHeight < 20; stackHeight++) {
            const block = document.createElement('a-entity');

            block.setAttribute('geometry', {
              primitive: 'box',
              width: 0.5,
              height: 0.5,
              depth: 0.025
            });

            block.setAttribute(
              'position',
              `0 ${stackHeight * 0.5} -5`
            );

            block.setAttribute('material', 'color', COLOURS.default);

            sceneElement.appendChild(block);

            block.addEventListener('mouseenter', blockMouseEnter);
            block.addEventListener('mouseleave', blockMouseLeave);
          }
        }
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a-scene stacks>
      <a-entity position="1 1.6 1" rotation="0 45 0">
        <a-camera>
          <a-cursor></a-cursor>
        </a-camera>
      </a-entity>
      <a-sky color="#5CC8FA"></a-sky>
    </a-scene>
  </body>
</html>
```

[This is video of the problem](https://gfycat.com/UnimportantFlawedAuklet), where there should never be more than one yellow brick.

Does anyone know why this might be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be fixed in master versions of A-Frame soon going out as 0.8.2. Try https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/commit/000e669f8eb242ed7b1fe2ef45c5607d99d46609